# Where is Fabric getting the default user from?

Tags: fabric

The Fabric [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#environment-as-configuration) states:

> Fabric defaults to your local username when making SSH connections

My standard username is `dserodio`, so there are references to this username in quite a few of my dotfiles, but on this network my username is `dserodi`, and Fabric is not getting the default username right:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['USER']
'dserodi'
>>> from fabric.operarations import *
>>> print env['user']
'dserodio'
>>> print env['local_user']
'dserodio'
```

Where's Fabric getting this default username from?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric can get a username from a few places

- by default, fabric uses a operating-system independent method of working out the [user](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/d6676f6a1051513c70452ceb27feda2ad86e6d4e/fabric/state.py#L268) you are logged in as.
- but it can be overridden for all hosts using [`env.user`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#user)  (or via `-u` or `--user` [command line option](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-u))
- or it can be overridden for one (or more) hosts in [`env.hosts`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#defining-host-lists) (or via `-H` or `--hosts` [command line option](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-H))
- it can be overridden temporarily for a block in a [settings context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings)
- it can be overridden temporarily for a single task using a call to [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html?highlight=execute#fabric.tasks.execute)
- if you have [`env.use_ssh_config = True`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#ssh-config) set, then your `~/.ssh/config` may introduce an alias that includes a username.

But my guess is that you've got a [`~/.fabricrc`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#rcfile) or some other file specified with (`-c` or `--config`) that has an additional username passed in.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.fabricrc and didn't specify any file with `-c` or `--config`